# Не работает добавление данных (INSERT INTO) в таблицу

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Здравствуйте.

Начал изучать PHP, с книги Head First PHP & MySQL, дошел до раздела в котором нужно добавить данные из заполненной формы в базу данных.

Выполнил все сначала, так сказать, своими словами, не работает. Дальше скачал готовые файлы с сайта книги, попытался найти где я ошибся, не нашел. Плюнул, заменил содержимое своих файлов содержимым из файлов книги, тоже не работает.

Код:

```
$first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
$last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
$when_it_happened = $_POST['whenithappened'];
$how_long = $_POST['howlong'];
$how_many = $_POST['howmany'];
$alien_description = $_POST['aliendescription'];
$what_they_did = $_POST['whattheydid'];
$fang_spotted = $_POST['fangspotted'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$other = $_POST['other'];

$dbc = mysql_connect("мой_хост", "пользователь", "пароль", "имя_базы")
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

$query = "INSERT INTO `aliens_abduction` (first_name, last_name, when_it_happened, how_long, " .
"how_many, alien_description, what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email) " .
"VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$when_it_happened', '$how_long', '$how_many', " .
"'$alien_description', '$what_they_did', '$fang_spotted', '$other', '$email')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error querying database.');

mysqli_close($dbc);

echo 'Thanks for submitting the form.<br />';
echo 'You were abducted ' . $when_it_happened;
echo ' and were gone for ' . $how_long . '<br />';
echo 'Number of aliens: ' . $how_many . '<br />';
echo 'Describe them: ' . $alien_description . '<br />';
echo 'The aliens did this: ' . $what_they_did . '<br />';
echo 'Was Fang there? ' . $fang_spotted . '<br />';
echo 'Other comments: ' . $other . '<br />';
echo 'Your email address is ' . $email;
```

Высвечивается ошибка Error querying database.
 Запрос на создание таблицы сначала делал сам, потом удалил, на всякий случай, и сделал запрос из файла книги:

```
CREATE TABLE `aliens_abduction` (
  `first_name` VARCHAR(30),
  `last_name` VARCHAR(30),
  `when_it_happened` varchar(30),
  `how_long` VARCHAR(30),
  `how_many` VARCHAR(30),
  `alien_description` VARCHAR(100),
  `what_they_did` VARCHAR(100),
  `fang_spotted` VARCHAR(10),
  `other` VARCHAR(100),
  `email` VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Предполагаю, что не всю информацию предоставил, спрашивайте, что нужно предоставлю.
Прошу помочь, кто чем может?
Если пошлете в Google, то хоть намекните состав запроса, область поиска.

Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите мануал по `mysqli_error` Выведите текст запроса, запустите запрос напрямую к базе, в общем ваша цель - получить конкретное описание ошибки.

Comment: И кстати если ваша книга рекомендует добавлять в БД путем подставления значений прямо в текст запроса - я вам рекомендую ее сжечь сразу и гуглить в сторону prepared statements.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.
По поводу сжечь, это просто только начало раздела работы с базой данных, предполагаю что более безопасные подходы будут показаны дальше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом коде две принципиальные ошибки.

1. Переменные подставляются в запрос напрямую, а не через плейсхолдеры.
2. Отсутствует обработка ошибок mysql (Бессмысленная фраза "Error querying database" таковой считаться не может). А только прочитав сообщение об ошибке, можно понять, в чем проблема. Это принципиальный момент. Узнать причину ошибки можно только у своей системы. Посторонних людей спрашивать бесполезно.

Поскольку в mysqli работа с плейсхолдерами сложна до такой степени, что новички в принципе неспособны освоить её самостоятельно, то вместо mysqli надо надо сразу учить PDO.

Чтобы ошибки mysql отображались, надо перед соединением с БД написать строчку

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

а все чудовищные "or die()" из кода надо наоборот удалить подчистую и не писать больше никогда.

Если после этого запустить код, то ошибка будет выведена на экран или туда, куда обычно выводятся все ошибки. Её надо будет прочесть и исправить.

Но повторюсь, вместо mysqli надо в обязательном порядке использовать PDO. Это все равно придется делать в будущем, поэтому чем раньше, тем лучше. Вот [хорошее руководство](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, за совет.

Вышла такая ошибка:
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in /home/..../report.php on line 36.

On line 36, следующее: $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)